# setup customizable options for all simple products via db in magento 2

Tags: magento, product, customization, magento2

I would like to add the custom  option for all simple products via db in magento 2 i can manually import the custom option for the first product one by one but there are 10k+ products so i can't do it.

I already check but find nothing, only a paid plugin for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import custom option via CSV file is the better way instead of manual import.
Follow the steps to import the custom options:

1.Create CSV file with column name: sku,store_view_code,has_options,custom_options
 For eg.

```
sku,has_options,custom_options,store_view_code 
24-MB01,,1,"name=Sample Custom Option,type=drop_down,required=1,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=498,file_extension=,image_size_x=,image_size_y=,option_title=60 cm x 80 cm|name=Sample Custom Option,type=drop_down,required=1,price=0.7000,price_type=fixed,sku=499,file_extension=,image_size_x=,image_size_y=,option_title=60 cm x 90 cm"
```

2.Go to System > Data Transfer > Import

3.Select entity type "products"

4.Select the CSV file

5.Click on check data button

6.If CSV is in correct format then it will display import button.

7.Start import by clicking on import Button

Your Custom Options for Simple products will be imported successfully.

**Note**:

- This Import will work only for importing Simple Product Custom Options
- Keep store_view_code field blank, It is a mandatory field to import product otherwise it will fail while checking CSV data.

Comment: Thank you sir! I also found out a way of doing it with an stored procedure.